# Java target/select class/object - confused (sorry for bad title)

Tags: java, class, object, inheritance, methods

What I have below is producing the desired results by print some employee details along with weekly / monthly wages as appropriate.

However I understand that I should not be inputting data in the constructor as I've done.

I need to prompt for a hours worked value only for "PartTimeEmployees", just not the way I've done it.

I've tested with For-Each loops, Enhanced For loops and using the instanceOf operator.

If I could get some guidance/hints or examples of how to accomplish what is currently being done in the constructor, but in the TestEmployee class instead that would be great.

Mostly I'm not sure how to even describe what I'm trying to achieve. This hinders Googling somewhat. (Help with a better title would also be great)

Thanks in advance.

```
public class TestEmployee
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int size;
        Employee[] employees = new Employee[4];
        employees[0] = new FullTimeEmployee("Jane", 26000);
        employees[1] = new PartTimeEmployee("Jack");
        employees[2] = new FullTimeEmployee("Lucy", 52000);
        employees[3] = new PartTimeEmployee("Lenny");

        for(int i = 0; i < employees.length; i++)
        {
        employees[i].print();
        }

    }
}
```

Class: PartTimeEmployee - Constructor:

```
public PartTimeEmployee(String thisName)
{
    super(thisName);

    System.out.println("Please enter the number of hours worked by " + thisName + ": ");
    numHours = keyboard.nextInt();

    setHours(numHours);
}
```

Comment: Taking user input in the constructor seems really odd to me. Besides that I'd probably use a common class and distinguish full time and part time by the hours (and I also suspect part time employees do earn something ;) ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your question, below might fit with your need -

First of all create generic `Employee` class -

```
class Employee {

    private String name;
    private int workingHours;
    private final boolean IS_PART_TIME_EMP;

    public Employee(String name, int workingHours) {
        this.name = name;
        this.workingHours = workingHours;
        this.IS_PART_TIME_EMP = false;
    }

    public Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.IS_PART_TIME_EMP = true;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getWorkingHours() {
        return workingHours;
    }

    public void setWorkingHours(int workingHours) {
        this.workingHours = workingHours;
    }

    public boolean isPartTimeEmployee() {
        return IS_PART_TIME_EMP;
    }
}
```

Now you can use it as per your requirement.

```
Employee[] employees = new Employee[4];
employees[0] = new Employee("Jane", 26000);
employees[1] = new Employee("Jack");
employees[2] = new Employee("Lucy", 52000);
employees[3] = new Employee("Lenny");

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

for (Employee employee : employees) {
    if(employee.isPartTimeEmployee()) {
        System.out.println("Please enter working hours by " + employee.getName() + ": ");
        int numHours = sc.nextInt();
        employee.setWorkingHours(numHours);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was attempting to achieve. I already have a generic Employee class (also PartTimeEmployee and FullTimeEmployee classes, should have probably mentioned that before). I never though of using a Boolean here for PartTimeEmployee. Also the For loop is great!Thanks so much! You've made my day! :)

Answer (score 0):

Constructor is not meant for user input.Its main intention is to initialize object of that class.

Instead of doing that in constructor,you can try something like this

```
employees[1] = new PartTimeEmployee("Jack");
System.out.println("Please enter the number of hours worked by " + employees[1].getName()+ ": ");
numHours = keyboard.nextInt();
employees[1].setHours(numHours);
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely will have some logical main loop in your program, like

```
while(!quit) {
    // 1. ask if you want to add part time or full time employee
    // 2. ask proper questions
    // 3. call correct constructor
}
```

Writing such small pseudo code algorithm should be self explanatory and get you going.

Step one: presentation of options available for user and reading user input.
Step two: performing actions depending on user input from step 1
Step three: final call to proper constructor depending on results from steps 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly (which I'm really not sure of) you want to prompt for the employee data in the main method.

In that case I'd use a loop and query the following things:

- name of the employee
- does the employee work full time? (y/n)
- if yes: what is the wage? (assume hours = whatever a full time employee works a day)
- if no: how many hours? (and probably the hourly wage as well)

Then use that information to construct an `Employee` object (I don't see any need for the subclasses here).